# ¿Para qué se usa la etiqueta [archivo]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Estaba mirando [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288642/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-simplexlsx/288654#288654), sobre la cual no tengo queja alguna :) y vi que existe una etiqueta [archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archivo) con 364 preguntas al día de hoy (incluyendo esta pregunta).

¿En qué casos debería usarse esta etiqueta? (¿O es plausible pensar en echarle napalm encima y quemarla?)

Comment: tal vez haya que encontrarle una explicacion de cuando usarla.. pero me parece bien para lectura y escritura de archivos.

Comment: Aunque podría ser de utilidad (p.e. para I/O en ficheros), es muy amplia y transversal y eso no la hace de mucha utilidad... y algo me dice que, al ser tan genérica y amplia, seguramente no se use correctamente. Huele a meta-etiqueta.

Comment: Coincido con @AlvaroMontoro. Cabe mencionar que si bien la etiqueta cuenta con resume y wiki estos no incluyen la orientación de uso de rigor.

Comment: Creo que con esa orientación sería más fácil para todos, incluyendo los casos en los que uno decide si edita las etiquetas de una pregunta :)

Comment: Seguramente la respuesta mas apropiada para este caso incluirá una propuesta de orientación de uso para [tag:archivo] o bien  sugerencias para hacer una [meta-tag:solicitud-de-quemado] si no es que la liga a tal publicación.